# calculate year of birth based on given age of person

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

How can I calculate birth year based on given age of person using SQL Server, 
for eg his age is 30, result should be displayed as 01/01/1985 .

Thanks to all!

Comment: Someone born in August through December of 1984 would still be 30. There's not enough information in just the age to know exactly what year they were born.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how accurate it would be but you can try like below

Since the person is 30 years age, he have already passed `30*365` days, which is `10950` days. So use a `DATEADD()` funcrtion like

```
select '01/01/' + cast(dateadd(day,-10950,getdate()) as varchar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide information how the exact month and day would be calculated, it would be impossible to return the exact date. Here is how you can calculate the year rather easily:

```
declare @age int = 30;

select convert(varchar(10),dateadd(year,-(@age),getdate()),101)
```